# Cross-domain communication with a frame within a frame

Tags: javascript, iframe, xss

I have a page that includes another page on a different domain in an iframe. The page contained in the iframe is a frameset with another frame.

```
   <!--- page-that-I-control.html --->
   <script src="https://my-web-site.com/recipient.js">
   <iframe id="frame_a" src="https://www.third-party-vendor.com/frameset.html">

   <!--- frameset.html --->
   <frameset>
   <frame id="frame_b" src="https://www2.third-party-vendor.com/innermost-frame.html"> 
   </frameset>

   <!--- innermost-frame.html --->
   <script src="https://my-web-site.com/sender.js">
```

I'm using [postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) to get around the same-origin policy, and that works great, but postMessage() isn't supported by IE7.

Is there any way to get around the same origin party and send a message from sender.js to recipient.js that works in IE7?

Comment: I see there are shims to support postMessage() in IE7 that work by changing the hash string in the URL containing the frame. I've succeeded in sending a message from sender.js to recipient.js using `window.location.top = "https://my-web-site.com/page-that-i-control.html#" + message`, but that assumes I know the name of `page-that-i-control.html` at runtime, which, unfortunately, I don't.

Comment: I thought, no problem, I'll just use the URL hash to to tell the `#frame_b` the name of the page that contains it. But the frameset gets in the way. I can't find any way to get a reference to `#frame_b` from the outermost window.

Comment: You can post a message to the page containing the frames, and have this page forward the post to the other frame.

Comment: @Gerben That's a good suggestion, thanks. I currently don't have a script on the frameset page. If no other solution arises, I'll ask the vendor if they can add one.

Comment: Can't you do window.top.location = "#" + message ?

Comment: Maybe window.name is an other option.

Comment: @Gerben Somehow I got the impression that I had to set location to a full URL, but now that you mention it, `window.top.location = "#" + message` seems like it ought to work. I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: Does this work for you?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187103/xss-security-communication-between-2-iframes-from-the-same-domain/2190728

Comment: @Gerben Okay, `window.top.location = "#message"` changes the URL to the URL of my frame + the message (instead of the URL of the top window + the message). That's why I need the frame to know the URL of the top window.

Comment: @Erlend Thanks. That doesn't solve my problem, but it's helpful.