# Sharing objects between iframes of the same domain

Tags: javascript

If I have a window in domain X with two iframes in domain Y,
Can I share an object between the two iframes?

There are two options I am aware of, and they only let you share data, not objects:

- Through cookies with pooling - CPU intensive and need to deal with data race situations
- As described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2190728/777203 - Doesn't work in chrome  (appears in error log as if the parent window tried to access the sibling iframe)
  But both methods just

In addition to the issues described near each method, they only allow you to share data and not objects.

Theoretically, security constraints shouldn't apply because the two frames are on the same domain.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you control the main page and iframe pages? If yes, you can allow cross-domain communication using the [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) method/event.

Comment: I do not control the container page.
(That would also just let me share data only and not objects)

Comment: I found if you create an object on the root page, child iframes and tabs can create and access properties on that object, and it seems to use shared memory across processes. Even functions can be stored on that object, and they run in the context of the frame that set the function, even if called from another frame. All frames seem to use the same event queue and you don't have to worry about multithreading. To do this, on your parent frame: window.sharedObject = {}; then on child frames: window.sharedObject = (opener ? opener.window.sharedObject : parent.sharedObject);

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably be able to share objects if the iframes could get a hold of a reference to each other. If the container page is hosted on a different domain than the sibling iframes, though, I am not sure how you can get this reference. As a result, I think you'd only be able to share data, either via localStorage or postMessage or something.